# In Python Celery, how do I persist objects across consecutive worker calls?

Tags: python, celery

I'm using Celery to automate some screen scraping. I'm using Selenium to open up a Chrome webdriver, manipulate the page, save some data, and then move on to the next page in the queue. The problem is that it builds up and breaks down the web driver for every task in the queue, which is very time consuming and resource intensive.

How do I persist objects across calls? I've read some things about connection pooling in Celery, but it's not clear to me how exactly this works - where do I build up the webdriver - in the tasks file or in the main queueing file? If the latter, how do the workers know which webdriver to use?

Example:

scrape.py:

```
for page in list:  
  scrape.delay(str(row['product_id']), str(row['pg_code']))
```

tasks.py:

```
def scrape:
  # do some stuff
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to either configure multiple workers in Celery or to pool access to the web driver. Have you tried using eventlet?

Comment: Have you considered using scrapy instead? It's a framework specifically designed for scraping sites and better suited for this task than celery.

Comment: I investigated scrapy, but it wasn't the best fit, as I needed to scrape data after interacting with some Javascript-driven page elements. scrapy's best practice approach is to simulate the API calls and scrape those. My use case is actually an integration test, so testing the API calls is possible, but less than ideal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since each worker instantiates the task as a singleton, you can cache the web driver in the task object. The documentation specifically suggests this approach.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#instantiation

Comment: Wow, this works amazingly well and was very simple! Too bad this was buried in the docs in an area I wouldn't have looked. Any suggestions on how to go about closing the driver (or in the case of the docs example, the DB connection)? I would want to close it when the worker is freed, but I didn't see in the docs how to specify that. Overall, this is a minor issue for my use case, but seems valuable for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Yes, it can be hard to find things in the celery docs. 

You should be able to clean up in the `__del__` method.

Comment: Can you help clarify how to use __del__ properly? Here's what I wrote, with no success as part of my new ChromeTask class: 
def __del__(self):
    if self._driver is not None:
      return self._driver.close()

But when the celery autoscaler kills off processes, the driver clearly isn't being closed, as the Chrome windows stay open. When the autoscaler scales back up again, I get more new Chrome windows in addition to the zombie ones left behind.

Comment: The `__del__` method gets called when the object gets garbage collected. So it sounds like the garbage collector can't close the chrome instance. I don't now the details on how the autoscaler works but you may be able to hook into it somehow to do your clean up.